# Invoking a static member function on non-existing object

Tags: c++, static, language-lawyer

Something like this just came up in another question and piqued my interest. Given that `Foo` is declared like this:

```
struct Foo
{
     static void bar() {std::cout << "Bar!";}
};
```

doing something like this seems to work just fine:

```
std::vector<Foo> v;
v[10].bar();
```

However, is this usage actually legal? What if `bar()` weren't declared `static`?

Comment: It's legal. If `bar()` wasn't static it would still be legal, of course.

Comment: UB due to accessing non-existing element of `std::vector`.

Comment: Calling the function is irrelevant, `v[10]` is UB already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [[class.static]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.static#1) (emphasis mine):

> A static member s of class X may be referred to using the qualified-id
>   expression X​::​s; it is not necessary to use the class member access
>   syntax to refer to a static member. **A static member may be referred to
>   using the class member access syntax, in which case the object
>   expression is evaluated**.

`v[10]` *must* be evaluated, `bar` being static or not is immaterial. The vector will be accessed out of bounds for sure, so it's definitely undefined behavior.

Answer (score 9):

> doing something like this seems to work just fine:

That doesn't mean it's OK.

Please read http://c-faq.com/ansi/experiment.html which has a great analogy from Roger Miller:

*"Somebody told me that in basketball you can't hold the ball and run. I got a basketball and tried it and it worked just fine. He obviously didn't understand basketball."*

Accessing `v[10]` is undefined behaviour. It doesn't matter if you call a member function on it, even just accessing `v[10]` is undefined. (And as pointed out in the comment, the object expression is evaluated even when calling a static member function, which IMHO should be obvious, because `v[10]` is not used in an unevaluated context like `sizeof(v[10])` or `decltype(v[10])`).

You cannot write C++ code with the view "this seems to work just fine" and assume that means the program is correct.

Comment: nice analogy. I will get a basketball and try it myself asap ;)

Comment: "You cannot write C++ code with the view "this seems to work just fine" and assume that means the program is correct." Isn't asking "Is this legal?" the exact opposite of doing that? Apart from that, the question is of course purely hypethical, to understand the inner workings of code like this. I can't see why anybody would ever want to do something like this.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I don't think it's that obvious. One can easily fall into the trap of thinking that if part of an expression isn't required, it isn't evaluated (I've had this conversion with a C++ novice myself, about static members btw). So I think it's good the standard spells it out.

Comment: @Knoep, I wasn't commenting on the "is this legal?" part, only the "this seems to work fine" part. Unfortunately in many cases appearing to work fine is only loosely correlated with being valid C++!

Comment: I know that. That is why I asked this question. Asking  "It works, but is it legal?" wouldn't have made much sense if I hadn't known that there is a difference between the two, would it? "This seems to work fine" is simply a necessary precondition for asking this question. If it hadn't worked in the first place, there would have been no point in asking if it was valid (apart from suspecting a compiler bug for no reason).

Answer (score -3):

both declaration of the function "bar" is okay and both are legal too.
the only difference occurs when you intend to use the "bar" function across different files.
void bar() has global scope, means you can use it in any file(files other than "bar" exist)

but static void bar() will have file scope, means you can still use it inside the parent file, but not outside the that file.

otherwise, both are correct.

Comment: No, this is a static member function. The keyword `static` here means something completely different.